# How to add an Knockout custom function in Typescript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to bind an event on my observable array so that when the input (eg, description has changed it will trigger the function. I've been reading different solutions online but none of them seem to work using Typescript. Here is my code below.

HTML:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: income">
<tr>
<td><input data-bind="value: description, event: {change: save} "/></td>
<td><input data-bind="value: amount"/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Typescript:

```
ko.observableArray.fn['save'] = function () {
  // does something
}
income = ko.observableArray([{ description: 'Description', amount: '0'}]);
this.addIncome.save();
```

It is telling me that Property 'saveExtendedBalance' does not exist on type 'KnockoutObservableArray'. How do I rewrite this?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen you have a problem declaring your knockout observable array, if you want initialize your array at least with one object, you have to change this line:

`income = ko.observableArray({ description: 'Description', amount: '0'});`

to this:

`income = ko.observableArray([{ description: 'Description', amount: '0'}]);`

This is because you have to initialize and always treat this variable `income` like an array an you are initializing like object.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to type the square brackets when I wrote the question but they are in my script, so the problem is still there. I edited the question to reflect the correct code.

Comment: Your solution could be something like this in your html code `<td><input data-bind="value: description,  event: {change: $root.save} "/></td>` then on your VM add this function `this.save = function(){
    alert("Hola")
}`... Let me know if this work for you.

Comment: $root didn't work for me but $parent did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete and functionnal example of what you want:

I also made you a function for removing element from you array.

There is the typescript code:

```
class TestAdd {
    dummyArray: KnockoutObservableArray<string> = ko.observableArray([]);
    dummyToAdd: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable("");

    save = ():void => this.dummyArray.push(this.dummyToAdd());

    deleteElement = (elementToDelete: string):string[] => this.dummyArray.remove(elementToDelete);
}

ko.applyBindings(new TestAdd(), document.getElementById("Test"));
```

And the HTML code:

```
<section id="test">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: dummyToAdd, event: {change: save}">
    <h3 data-bind="visible: dummyArray().length > 0">Your array:</h3>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: dummyArray">
        <li><span data-bind="text: $data"></span> - <button data-bind="click: $parent.deleteElement">Delete element</button></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

In my dependencies I'm using `"@types/knockout": "^3.4.38"`